# Azure database profile

Tags: performance, azure

I am possibly moving to Azure for my we hosting, but am not understanding the profiler. What is 'run count'? If it's the number of times this exact query is run, the surely the other columns are averages?

Is there a way to show each execution of a query?

[image]